# I can't seem to use two inheritance for my java, extending a class in another class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

```
package Graph;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

Below here is my class which covers all other classes, and extends JFrame, which I have created by selecting "new > Java Frame" options in Netbeans.I created this in a package called Graph, and this filename is GraphFrame.Java.

```
public class GraphFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public GraphFrame() {

}
```

The lines below is from my JFrame auto creating codes.

```
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
```

These lines below here is my main method

```
public static void main(String args[]) {


    /* Create and display the form */
    //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        //public void run() {
            GraphFrame Frame=new GraphFrame();
            Frame.setVisible(true);
            Frame.setTitle("Functional Dependency");
            Frame.setSize(500, 500);

        //}
   // });
}
```

These lines is my DrawGraph class, which I created INSIDE the GraphFrame class. Besides that, it extends my JPanel which I made by dragging the JPanel icon from the Swing Containers (Sorry if that is the wrong way to add JPanel)

```
class DrawGraph extends JPanel{
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawLine(10, 100, 380, 100);
    g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 190);

    g.drawLine(380, 100, 370, 90);
    g.drawLine(380, 100, 370, 110);
    g.drawLine(200, 30, 190, 40);
    g.drawLine(200, 30, 210, 40);

    g.drawString("X", 360, 80);
    g.drawString("Y", 220, 40);




    }

}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

My problem is, the lines of graph which I have coded, did not appear.I have googled, StackOverflowed, browsed through my lab exercises, and I can't seem to find the solution to this. Yes, this may need more reading, but to be honest, I couldn't quite understand what's wrong.

Comment: If you extend JFrame you need to call the super constructor in your class.

Comment: if you extend a class that has a constructor with no arguments, you don't need to call the super constructor explicitly the compiler does that for you. his problem is that the panel he built isn't added to the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never add your JPanel to the frame you created.

This should do what you want.

```
public class GraphFrame extends JFrame {

private DrawGraph graph;

public GraphFrame(){
    super();
    graph = new DrawGraph();
    this.add(graph);
}
class DrawGraph extends JPanel{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(10, 100, 380, 100);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 200, 190);

        g.drawLine(380, 100, 370, 90);
        g.drawLine(380, 100, 370, 110);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 190, 40);
        g.drawLine(200, 30, 210, 40);

        g.drawString("X", 360, 80);
        g.drawString("Y", 220, 40);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this.add(graph) can be called because `GraphFrame` extends JFrame. The `.add()` method is a part of the JFrame class and can thus be called from `GraphFrame`

You should also consider creating a new file for the DrawGraph class as it can get messy if you want to add more functionality to either `GraphFrame or DrawGraph`.

Comment: So, it was not displayed not only because super(); , but also because of the 'add.()' ? wow...I have tried, and yes it worked. Thanks guys for the constructive suggestions and it seems like I need to study a lot more on super(); as well as JFrame and JPanel..
Thanks again, and I wish for all of you the best in life.

Comment: Yea the add method basically tells JFrame "This JPanel belongs to you". Glad i could help! good luck with your project!

Comment: And the part where I inherited in another class which already inherited, is correct I presume? No multiple inheritance there am I correct?

Comment: Yea correct, it's no multiple inheritance. You can treat this classes as separate. GraphFrame is one class and DrawGraph is another class. They have no connection to each other, other than being in the same file. If you put them in the same file you can only create the DrawGraph from the GraphFrame class, for example you cannot create DrawGraph from your main method.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're constructing a `GraphFrame` when you call the constructor for the object `Frame` (which should be `frame` btw). However, in this constructor, you still need to "create" the `JFrame` -- which is done in the constructor for the `JFrame` class.

All you have to do to call this super constructor for `JFrame` is put the following as the first line of your constructor in `GraphFrame`:

```
super();
```

Also, as the other answerer has mentioned, in order to view your panel, you have to add it to the `JFrame`. Therefore, in your main method (or better yet in your constructor for `GraphFrame`), add

```
DrawGraph panel = new DrawGraph();
this.add(panel);
```

Comment: Ok I have changed the 'Frame' to 'frame', cause I'm guessing this is related to strongtyping somehow.
Anyway, I have added the 
    super();

in the GraphFrame() { } as you  instructed, yet still cannot display my graph
I'm sorry if I'm too slow in this

Comment: I've edited my answer to include information about adding a panel to a created frame.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to refresh the page, sorry.. But yes your answer is true :)
I really appreciate your help on this