# Java graphs not appearing

Tags: java, swing, class

based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485657/i-cant-seem-to-use-two-inheritance-for-my-java-extending-a-class-in-another-cl>) I have learned that extending JFrame and JPanel is bad. So I have decided to ditch the idea and learnt how to code a frame, and its components ( I'm still learning by the way). But eventhough I have done the buttons,  I cannot seem to display my graph, and I am at my wits end now.

Below here is my first class, which has all the panels established and declared ( forgive me if the term is incorrect)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class OurUI {
   static Color kaler;
   private JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
   private JButton colorbutton1 = new JButton("Green");
   private JButton colorbutton2 = new JButton("Red");
   private JButton colorbutton3 = new JButton("Blue");
   private JPanel graphpanel = new JPanel();
   private JComponent[] GUIcomponents = { colorbutton1, colorbutton2,
         colorbutton3, };

   public OurUI() {
      for (JComponent comp : GUIcomponents) {
         mainpanel.add(comp);
      }
   }

   public JComponent getmaincomponent() {
      return mainpanel;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            OurGUI();
         }
      });
   }

   private static void OurGUI() {
      OurUI ourUI = new OurUI();
      JFrame guiframe = new JFrame("FUNCTIONAL DEPENDENCY");
      guiframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      guiframe.getContentPane().add(ourUI.getmaincomponent());
      guiframe.pack();// this code is for resizing the components, automatically
                      // so that we don't have to set the size
      guiframe.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      guiframe.setSize(500, 450);
      guiframe.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

These lines below are my other class, "DrawGraph". I'm not really good at coding, but I'm sure I did not call the class properly, just don't know how

```
 class DrawGraph
{
            DrawGraph drawgraph = new DrawGraph();
            static boolean lukis = true;   





             int oldY = 0;
             double degToRad (int deg){
            return ((2*Math.PI)/360.0) * deg;
            }

            int scale (int i, int width){
                return (int) ((i/(double)width)*720.0);}


            public void paintGraph(Graphics g){



                g.drawLine(0, 100, 400, 100);//X-axis
                g.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 200);//Y-axis
                g.drawLine(400, 100, 390, 90);//arrow pointing rightwards
                g.drawLine(400, 100, 390, 110);//arrow pointing rightwards
                g.drawLine(200, 0, 190, 10);//arrow pointing upwards
                g.drawLine(200, 0, 210, 10);//arrow pointing upwards

                g.drawString("X", 400, 80);//draw 'X' label
                g.drawString("Y", 220, 10);//draw 'Y' label

                g.drawString("\u03C0/2", 240, 120);//draw ' 1/2 Pi' label
                g.drawString("\u03C0", 290, 120);//draw 'Pi' label
                g.drawString("2\u03C0", 400, 120);//draw ' 2 Pi' label
                g.drawString("3\u03C0/2", 340, 120);//draw ' 3/2 Pi' label


                g.drawString("-\u03C0/2", 140, 120);//draw 'negative 1/2 Pi' label
                g.drawString("-\u03C0", 87, 120);//draw 'negative Pi' label
                g.drawString("-2\u03C0", 0, 120);//draw 'negative 2 Pi' label
                g.drawString("-3\u03C0/2", 30, 120);//draw ' 3/2 Pi' label



                g.drawString("0", 205, 110);//draw '0' label
                g.drawString("0.77", 175, 50);//draw '0.77' label for half Pi
                g.drawString("1", 175, 10);//draw '1' label for a Pi
                g.drawString("-0.77", 170, 150);//draw '0.77' label for half Pi
                g.drawString("-1", 185, 200);//draw '1' label for a Pi


                int width = 400;
                int height = 200;

                for (int i=0; i<width; i++){

                    int y = (int) Math.round((-Math.sin(degToRad(scale(i,width)))+1)*height/2.0);
                    if (lukis && i>0){

                        g.drawLine(i-1, oldY, i, y);
                           } 


                    else {
                        g.drawLine(i, y, i, y);

                          }


                oldY = y;
                }
  }
}
```

Edit : I think I have cleaned the code indentations enough, correct me if I'm wrong. And yes, I made some mistakes, which were unprofessional so pardon me on that.

Comment: *It's me, again with the java graphs not appearing* Great title :D

Comment: Yes "*It's me again...*" just makes you want to down-vote it without farther reading (not that I did).

Comment: Yeah, that was on me :( but thanks for the downvotes from other people though, I will try to be more professional.

Comment: First class code has been re-formatted.

Comment: I'm really sorry for burdening you, and I will take this as a lesson to indent better.

Regarding the question, I have followed you instructions and called the class, which I have succeeded.

I have coded this line /*  guiframe.add(new DrawGraph());   */
just before /*   guiframe.pack();   */ and it has given me the graph, but the buttons are gone, somehow. 



Edit : Silly mistake, I have put it below  /* guiframe.pack();  */  and the buttons are there again. Thank you @hovercraft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have learned that extending JFrame and JPanel is bad

But if you need to draw in the GUI, you often need to extend JPanel, and that's exactly what you should do here. For example the code where you draw with a Graphics object should be inside of the JPanel's `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. So your DrawGraph class **should** extend JPanel, and it should override paintComponent, complete with an `@Override` annotation on top, and should call the super method:

```
public class DrawGraph extends JPanel {
    // .... variables, constructor, methods here...

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // your painting code here
    }
```

Regarding,

```
guiframe.getContentPane().add(DrawGraph.paintComponent());
```

I have no idea what you're trying to do here, but as you know, it's wrong, delete that line, don't even approach anything like it in the future. It almost looks like you're trying to call a component's paintComponent method directly, something that you will almost never want to do.

Regarding:

> These lines below are my other class, "DrawGraph". I'm not really good at coding, but I'm sure I did not call the class properly, just don't know how...

but that's exactly what the tutorials are for. If you've not gone through them yet, please do so now:

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html): advanced tutorial on Swing graphics

Comment: Other side recommendations: code indentation and style is not optional or free form, but rather it needs to conform to standards. Your indentations and brace placement is all over the place, making your code very hard to read and understand. We appreciate it if you don't do this, if you put in the effort to clean up your code **before** posting it here. It's difficult enough to try to extract the gist of your problem and understand your code, so you don't want to make that any harder for us than necessary.

Comment: I have cleaned the code, as you strongly suggested, and I have to say getting an advice from you who have a vast experience in Java (based on your previous answers on java) really motivates me.

Regarding your answer, yes, all the errors, all the problems do go away after I learn from it. But there is the matter of calling the class. I will update ASAP.